# Perl creates objects very slowly

Tags: performance, perl, object

I have a perl script that reads ~50,000 rows from a database and stores them in an array of hashes.  Standard DBI code.  Rather than work directly on hashes, I prefer to put the data into objects that I can pass to other code modules very cleanly.  The table I'm reading from has 15+ columns in it.  My code basically looks like:

```
my $db = DBI->connect(); # Just pretend you see a proper DBI connect here
my $resultSet = $db->selectall_arrayref($sql);
$db->disconnect();

# Here's where the problem starts.
my %objects;
for my $row (@{$resultSet}) {
    my ($col1, $col2, ..., $col15) = @{$row};
    my %inputHash;
    $inputHash{col1} = $col1 if $col1;
    ...
    $inputHash{col15} = $col1 if $col15;
    my $obj = Model::Object->new(%inputHash);
    $objects{$col1} = $obj;
}
return values %objects;
```

It collects stuff into a hash to eliminate dups from the select.  The problem starts in the loop below the comment that says "Here's where the problem starts".  I've put a message in the loop to log a line for every 100 objects that are created.  The first 100 objects were created in 5 secs.  The next 100 took 16 secs.  Getting to 300 took 30 more secs.  It's up to 9000 objects and is taking 12+ minutes to create 100 objects.  I didn't think that 50,000 objects was large enough to create these kinds of issues.

The Model::Object that's being created is a class with getters and setters for each of the properties.  It has a new method and a serialize method (essentially a toString) and that's it.  There's no logic to it.

I'm running ActiveState Perl 5.16 on a Windows laptop with 8 GB of RAM, an i7 processor (3 yrs old) and an SSD drive with reasonable space.  I've seen this on a Linux machine with the same version of Perl, so I don't think it's a hardware thing.  I need to stay on 5.16 of AS Perl.  Any advice about how to improve performance would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: did you check the performance without creating the $obj (or even %inputHash) ? the performance problem seems related to hashing.

Comment: If performance is a problem, then you should convert your `my $obj = Model::Object->new(%inputHash);` line to `my $obj = \%inputHash`, just for the purpose of testing.  Benchmark again.  If the change makes nearly no difference, then `Model::Object` is not your problem.  if it makes a big difference, then it may well be.

Comment: Performance tuning is easier to do if you have some idea of what the best possible outcome could be before starting down a rabbit hole.  For all we know the real problem could be the code you've passed over with `...`.

Comment: @DavidO: While I generally agree with you that no code should be left out, in this case, the surroundings strongly suggest that its just 13 assignments into the `$inputHash`. Also, profiling is a much better way to find the slow line instead of "shotgun profiling".

Comment: What is the structure inside `Model::Object`? Can you not simply say `$objects{$input_hash{col1}} = bless \%input_hash, 'Model::Object'` instead of invoking the constructor? And do you always want the data corresponding to the *last* value of `col1`? If the *first* one will do then you can save a lot of work building `%input_hash` when it is only going to be thrown away. You could also iterate backwards over `$result_set` to pick up the last values in the list

Comment: Thank you all for the excellent suggestions!  I will try several of these, though it may take me a couple days.  I need to gain familiarity with the profiler and I have a couple other things to do in my job.  I will post back as soon as I can with what I discover. @borodin: 
I gave a short desc of Model::Object.  It's mostly properties, but has a serialize method we need.  It needs the constructor.

Comment: @limeri: Are you sure? I can't imagine that the contents of your object are very much different from what is in `%input_hash`

Answer (score 5):

First of all: **Profile your program!** You already have narrowed it down to one sub, with [`Devel::NYTProf`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf) (for example) you can narrow it down to the line that is the culprit.

Here are some general considerations from my side:

Just from glancing over it, some probable slowing factors immediately spring to mind, but you can't be sure if you don't **profile your program**:

Mayhe hashing-allocation takes too long. As your `%objects` hash grows, perl will steadily allocate more memory.
You could pre-set the size of your `$objects` hash. This feature is [documented here](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perldata.pod#Scalar-values). Since this is a memory allocation problem, you wouldn't recognize this, if you **profile** with a too small data set.

```
# somewhere outside of the loop
keys(%objects) = $number_of_rows * 1.2;
# the hash should be a little bigger than the objects to be stored in it
```

Secondly, it could be that the object-creation takes too long. Take a look at `Model::Object`. I don't know what's in there so I can't make a comment about that. But most certainly you should consider passing the `%inputHash` as a reference. With `Model::Object->new(%inputHash);`, You put the keys and values on the stack, and then retrieve it, in the worst case as `my %options = @_;`. With that move, you recompute the hash for every key.

Maybe you can come up with a way to get rid of the small `$inputHash` completely. I quickly only can come up with some ways, that would be based on `defined`nes, but you are checking for truthyness (are you sure that's right, btw? `"0"` is false, for example).

But again, most importantly: **Profile your program.** Maybe take a smaller data set, but you wouldn't be able to see the memory allocation problems as clearly then. But with **profiling** you will exactly see, at which point your program takes the most time.

[`The perldoc` has something to say about speeding up your program](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlperf.html). It has a nice chapter about **profiling**, too.

Comment: ***...in the worst case as `my %options = @_;`. With that move, you recompute the hash for every key*** very good point

Comment: Thank you all for the advice, especially about Devel::NYTPRof!  I've been playing some with it and have found some interesting results.  We use Params::Validate in all of our classes and it is being called an extraordinary number of times and taking up the most time.  So I'm investigating what in my logic is doing that.  I do have one question, the NYTProf returned a message for one module that said, "variables that impact regex performance for whole application seen here".  I was trying to figure out what it meant, but Google wasn't very helpful.  Any ideas about that?

Comment: I found the answer to my question about the variables that impact regex performance.  Thanks!

Comment: Just for future references: you probably use `$\``, $& or `$'` somewhere usage of these have a bad preformance impact on all regex matches. It's better to use the `p` flag and its corresponding variables.

Answer (score 1):

As you have read, it is imperative that you use a profiler to determine where the bottlenecks are in your code before you progress far with optimising. However, as I described in my comment, it is possible to rewrite your loop differently so that unused hashes aren't unnecessarily created and discarded

You should also see an improvement from passing the hash by reference instead of as a simple list of keys and values

Here's a modification of your code that should give you some ideas

```
use constant COLUMN_NAMES => [ qw/
  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
  col6  col7  col8  col9  col10
  col11 col12 col13 col14 col15 
/ ];

sub object_results {

    my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass);
    my $result_set = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($sql);
    $dbh->disconnect;

    my %objects;
    for ( my $i = $#$result_set; $i >= 0; --$i ) {
        my $row = $result_set->[$i];
        next if exists $objects{$row->[0]};

        my %input_hash;
        for my $i ( 0 .. $#$row ) {
          my $v = $row->[$i];
          next unless defined $v;
          $input_hash{COLUMN_NAMES->[$i]} = $v;
        }

        $objects{$input_hash{col1}} = Model::Object->new(\%input_hash);
    }

    values %objects;
}
```

Comment: Small notice: You also could `use constant COLUMN_NAMES => qw/…/` and access it with `$input_hash{(COLNAMES)[$i]} = $v;`. scrapes off a few milliseconds and reduces complexity. But I rarely use constants maybe there is something with that usage that I don't know about.

Comment: Thank you for the extra hint.  In the real code, the column names are constants.  This code is a simplified and condensed version of the real code to make it to readable out of context.  In real life, I'd never use "col1" for an identifier.

Comment: @limeri: I guessed that. That's why I added the `COLUMN_NAMES` constant instead of auto-generating the column names. My code uses `COLUMN_NAMES->[$i]` instead of `'col'.($i+1)`. Remember that you shouldn't name variables according to the database column names either